# Managing SDF inside isolated storage with click once application

Tags: .net, wpf, sql-server-ce, isolatedstorage

My application is developed in WPF. I am using isolated storage to save some application data. I am using click once to deploy this application.

My issue is: on first run of my application I am creating a SQL Server CE database (`.sdf` file) in isolated storage.

```
using (SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString))
{
    engine.CreateDatabase();

    //Getting script from embedded resource file and split into individual queries
    var queries = GetScript("TestDB").Split(new string[] { "GO" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    //run script on database one by one
    using (SqlCeConnection sqlCeConnection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString)) //my connection string path is of isolated storage directory
    {
        sqlCeConnection.Open();

        foreach (var query in queries)
        {
            using (SqlCeCommand ceCommand = new SqlCeCommand(query, sqlCeConnection))
            {
                ceCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I want to migrate some changes in my existing database in isolated storage on client side I execute the script which I have added in my application as embedded resource.

```
 using (SqlCeConnection sqlCeConnection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString1))
                    {
                        sqlCeConnection.Open();

                        foreach (var query in queries)
                        {
                            using (SqlCeCommand ceCommand = new SqlCeCommand(query, sqlCeConnection))
                            {
                                ceCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I don't know why but wherever I publish new version through click once it generates new isolated storage location.

Even if I am getting a store as below which is for application.

```
IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
```

Thanks